# Is there a proper variable to track how many times a loop has looped?

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to coding, so forgive me if this is super obvious.

When running a `while` loop, and I want to only run if for a certain amount of times. Ex (python):

```
question_var = 0
while True:
  if condition:
    question_var += 1
    continue
  print("Condition not met")
```

I want to know if there is a proper variable to use in place of `question_var`. Similar to how `i` is used to represent index in a for loop. I understand that this is not necessary, but I just want to learn how to do it right. I have been using a variable named `rev`

Here is the actual program I am trying to run:

```
rev = 0
while rev <= 10:
  new_file_name = "C# is bad ({}).txt".format(rev)
  with open(new_file_name, 'w') as tempfile:
    tempfile.write("C# is bad.\nPython is good.\n")
  rev += 1
```

its a gag I made for my friend who likes C#, but when I was making it I felt the the variable `rev` seemed unprofesional.

Comment: loops don't have variables for this - you have to use own variable.

Comment: I think you're basically looking for `for i in range(certain_number_of_times):` instead of a `while` loop...?!

Comment: I am not sure if something like that exists. I have seen `counter` or `ctr` being used as convention, but really, there aren't any legacy terms AFAIK.

Comment: @deceze or `for iteration_number in itertools.count(1)` for an unbounded loop

Comment: I don't understand the question. Try posting a complete example which does exactly what you want it to, and then we'll see if there's anything better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using a `while True` loop is useful in some cases, but it is often not the most idiomatic use in python. As mentioned in the comments, you might find a `for` loop more appropriate:

```
for rev in range(0, 11):
  new_file_name = "C# is bad ({}).txt".format(rev)
  with open(new_file_name, 'w') as tempfile:
    tempfile.write("C# is bad.\nPython is good.\n")
```

Also, you don't really need to use `format()` here, you could change the second line to:

```
  new_file_name = f"C# is bad ({rev}).txt"
```

Comment: I am well aware that I can loop through the code 10 times whether I use a for loop or a while loop, but line 2 (line 3 if `rev = 0` is the first line) 
`new_file_name = "C# is bad ({}).txt".format(rev)`
I still need to access the rev variable

Comment: That's fine, `rev` can still be accessed using this solution.

Comment: If you just aren't sure what to call `rev`, people often just use `n`. Sometimes I call such variables `idx`.

Answer (score 0):

The code follows should be a working approach if you're using Python 3.8, but I can't test it currently since I'm on my phone

```py
counter = 0
maxLoops = 10
while (counter := counter++) < maxLoops:
    # do some magic
```

But a better approach is to use a for loop if you want to loop a certain amount.

```py
maxLoops = 10
for i in range(maxLoops):
    # do some magic
```

But there is no convention for how to run a while loop for a certain amount.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of the question you could use `for` and `break`:

```
need=2
for i in range(0,11):
  if i%3 == 0:
    print(i)
    need -= 1
    if need <= 0:
      break
print("i is {} after the loop".format(i))
```

Output:

> ```
> 0
> 3
> i is 3 after the loop
> ```

This loop will run at most 11 times, but finishes immediately when it finds the two special values it is looking for. Also, the loop variable remains accessible after the loop. Yeah, Python is different from C# here.

However, and this leads to the second part of the question, not knowing this means that you may rather want to implement something like this:

```
for rev in range(0, 11):
  new_file_name = "Python is new to me ({}).txt".format(rev)
  with open(new_file_name, 'w') as tempfile:
    tempfile.write("I will learn Python first.\nAnd even then I will not speak nonsense.\n")
```